# How to delete Unused Images?

Tags: 7, files, media

I am using Drupal 7. When I test my page speed in [Google PageSpeed Tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/), it says to compress the images. After that I compress the image and uploaded it. The uploaded image placed in files folder like (test_0.png) and the old name is test.png. I have lot of images like that. How to remove images which are not in use.

Answer (score 0):

Try [audit Files module](https://www.drupal.org/project/auditfiles)

> Audit files is designed to perform audits of your upload directory and
>   the corresponding database records. It will cross check that all files
>   in the database have a corresponding physical file, or it will check
>   that all files in the upload directory have a corresponding entry in
>   the database.
>
> This module can be helpful in identifying orphan files that have not
>   been deleted when their corresponding node was removed.
>
> The module has configurable options to ignore specified files and/or
>   directories.
>
> The reports allow you to permanently remove files or database entries
>   that represent orphans.

Answer (score 0):

All files uploaded via Drupal UI is managed in `file_managed` database table and the file usage is maintained in a separate table as `file_usage`.

There are couple of modules you can give a try for.

1. [Audit Files](https://www.drupal.org/project/auditfiles)
2. [Fancy File Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/fancy_file_delete)

Also you can write a query and delete all such which are no more in use. You can setup a cron job which periodically does that for you.

Sample Code: [source](https://www.drupal.org/node/733258)

```
//db_query to find all files not attached to a node:
$result = db_query("SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM file_usage WHERE file_managed.fid = file_usage.fid) ");

//Delete file & database entry
for ($i = 1; $i <= $result->rowCount(); $i++) {
  $record = $result->fetchObject();
  $file = file_load($record->fid);
  if ($file != NULL) {
    file_delete($file);
  } }
```